# Bogus C# - how to get completely randomized objects without listing RuleFor for every property?

Tags: c#, .net, faker, bogus

Using C# Bogus library, I would like to generate completely random objects without enumerating all fields as RuleFor explicitly.

How I could configure my Faker to achieve that?

Comment: You can't as far as i know, all generation in bogus is done via the `RuleFor` or `Faker` syntax. There are alternatives to `RuleFor`; [see this sample](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus#without-fluent-syntax). But this is probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try **AutoBogus** here: https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus

**AutoBogus** is a community extension written by **Nick Dodd** that "auto magically" creates default rules for properties of your POCO object. You can override those automatic rules that **AutoBogus** generates, in memory, with specific `RuleFor()` rules for unit test that expect specific values.